# PySpark: PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle CompiledFFI objects

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pickle

I'm new to the PySpark environment and came across an error while trying to encrypt data in an RDD with the cryptography module. Here's the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('encrypt').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv('test.csv', inferSchema = True, header = True)
df.show()
df.printSchema()

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

dfRDD = df.rdd
print(dfRDD)
mappedRDD = dfRDD.map(lambda value: (value[0], str(f.encrypt(str.encode(value[1]))), value[2] * 100))
data = mappedRDD.toDF()
data.show()
```

Everything works fine of course until I try mapping the `value[1]` with `str(f.encrypt(str.encode(value[1])))`. I receive the following error:

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle CompiledFFI objects

I have not seen too many resources referring to this error and wanted to see if anyone else has encountered it (or if via PySpark you have a recommended approach to column encryption).

Comment: I want to add that I'm using 2017 updated Mac, Jupyter Notebook and local PySpark downloaded via Homebrew...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> recommended approach to column encryption

You may consider Hive built-in encryption ([HIVE-5207](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5207), [HIVE-6329](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6329)) but it is fairly limited at this moment ([HIVE-7934](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7934)).

Your current code doesn't work because `Fernet` objects are not serializable. You can make it work by distributing only keys:

```
def f(value, key=key): 
    return value[0], str(Fernet(key).encrypt(str.encode(value[1]))), value[2] * 100

mappedRDD = dfRDD.map(f)
```

or

```
def g(values, key=key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    for value in values:
        yield value[0], str(f.encrypt(str.encode(value[1]))), value[2] * 100

mappedRDD = dfRDD.mapPartitions(g)
```